# How to execute a .clp made in CLIPS on command line

Tags: java, c, clips

I developed an expert system using CLIPS and would like to be able to run it on the command line. Is this possible?

My end goal is to have a Java program execute the .clp in CMD and pass the output and input to and from the command line and gui.

Can I run the project in clipsdos? If so how? Sorry for all the questions unofficial CLIPS documentation is sparse :(

Answer (score 1):

Create a file with a series of commands to execute:

```
(load rules.clp)
(reset)
(run)
```

You can then use the -f or -f2 option when launching CLIPS to execute the commands:

```
clips -f commands.bat
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! I attempted this before I asked this question. So I created a .bat but, clips is not a system work and there is no bin in the installation folders for me to add a path to. When I try to run this in ClipsDos it returns "clips". Any guidance will be much appreciated!

Comment: I just realized who you are..it is an honor to be helped by the Gary Riley!!

Comment: I can't determine what you did wrong based on the information you've provided.

Answer (score 0):

Look for CLIPS JNI: http://www.clipsrules.net/?q=Downloads/CLIPSJNI

On github you can find a lot of examples.